# Angular ngx-mask - Value not formatted

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I'm using this library [ngx-mask](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask) and I'm trying to mask some fields (dates and phone numbers) in Angular 11 with Reactive Forms.
Here are two snippets from my code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" mask="d0/M0/0000" [leadZeroDateTime]="true" [showMaskTyped]="true" required formControlName="dateOfBirth" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile-phone" mask="0000-0000" [showMaskTyped]="true" required formControlName="mobilePhone" />
```

But when I try to get the value from the form, the values are not formatted:

```
let formValue = this.createForm.value;
```

This is how it's shown in the UI

[image: Date input]
[image: Phone input]
But this is the result when I access the values
[image: Result]

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add one more mask option i.e `dropSpecialCharacters` like below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile-phone" mask="0000-0000" [showMaskTyped]="true" required formControlName="mobilePhone" [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" />
```

Please verify... And you can refer additional info from this ngx-mask documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Comment: [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" Doesn't seem to do the trick for me...

Comment: It should work. Here the link at the documentation if you need more information: https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask#dropspecialcharacters-boolean--string